# Required CommonsMultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present in spring boot

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot

I am trying to add feature of uploading excel to my spring boot application.

jsp:

```
<form action="/uploadpoifile/truepoi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="excelfile" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

bean:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="409600"/>
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="200000000"/>
</bean>
```

controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/uploadpoifile")
public class QcUploadPoiFileController {
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{poiType}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    void update(@RequestParam(value = "excelfile") CommonsMultipartFile file, @PathVariable(value = "poiType") String poiType){...}
}
```

After I selected excel I click upload and see error message:
`Required CommonsMultipartFile parameter 'excelfile' is not present`
What do I wrong?

Comment: can you show us the code?

Comment: Have you tried using MultipartFile instead of CommonsMultipartFile?

Comment: Please don't post code as images.

Comment: The same result as using MultipartFile.